# Laravel Query Builder: Get one item from each group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Basically I have a mini-library with multiple books, authors and dates of arrival.

```
|    Book    |   Author   |   Arrived   | For Sale | 
| ---------- | ---------- | ------------| -------- |
| HPotter V1 | Rowling    | 2010-01-01  | Yes      |
| HPotter V2 | Rowling    | 2010-02-01  | Yes      |
| S.Trek. V1 | Anonymous  | 2010-01-01  | No       |
| LotR. V1   | Tolkien    | 2010-02-01  | Yes      |
| LotR. V2   | Tolkien    | 2010-03-01  | Yes      |
| LotR. V3   | Tolkien    | 2010-04-01  | Yes      |
| LotR. V4   | Tolkien    | 2010-05-01  | Yes      |
| 50Shad. V1 | Satan      | 2010-06-01  | No       |
| Twilight 1 | Satan      | 2010-07-01  | No       |
```

Basically I need to get only **one Book For Sale for Group of Arrived Dates**. That means, I have to get one book for each of these dates:

- 2010-01-01
- 2010-02-01
- 2010-03-01
- 2010-04-01
- 2010-05-01

The last two books are not for sale, so they shouldn't be picked - I know it can be filtered with a simple `->where('For Sale', 'Yes')`.

The main idea is to push everything to the database instead of getting the whole list (it's kinda big) and manipulate it under Laravel.

Comment: Any random one would do? You can use the TOP 1 operator for that purpose

Comment: Yes, any random. How could use TOP 1 in Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you're looking for:

```
Book::where('For Sale', 'Yes')->groupBy('Arrived')->get();
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: For some reason it works, it gets one from every group. Now I'm curious, why is that?